# Laravel Flysystem SFTP connection

Tags: php, laravel

I've tried to save my data cross domain but in the same server using flysystem by campbell. https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Flysystem

But i cannot make it work using SFTP. Here is the error:

```
   Could not login with username: forge
```

Even i'm specift the privateKey but its not working. Here is my current setup:

```
   'sftp'      => [
        'driver'     => 'sftp',
        'host'       => 'xxxx.xxx.xxxx',
        'port'       => 22,
        'username'   => 'forge',
        'password'   => 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'privateKey' => '~/putty/privateKey.ppk',
        'root'       => 'cdn.example.com/public',
        'timeout'    => 10
    ],
```

i already install

```
   "league/flysystem-sftp": "~1.0"
```

Is there any other setup for using flysystem that i miss or is there any better way to save uploaded file to another domain?

*update:
I'm using Laravel Forge.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect via SSH to the remote host using the same details? It looks like it's a problem with the connection settings, not the code itself.

Comment: For example, try `ssh -v -i ~/putty/privateKey.ppk forge@xxxx.xxx.xxxx` from command line.

Comment: @Anthony yes it works perfectly. I even try change putty to git ssh. i can connect via git bash but not at the flysystem. Flysystem keep returning me  Could not login with username: forge

Comment: Your PEM is using `~` shorthand. Is the user that php runs under actually the user for that directory? If not, try setting value for privateKey to full path.

Comment: Hi. I've still tried connect it at local development. And i've tried using full path /c/Users/Mine/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: That doesn't mean that the user is the same. Have you tried full resolved path to the ppk? Like `/usr/myusername/putty/privateKey.ppk` or whatever `~` resolves to?

Comment: Yes. I'm using this C:/Users/Stefen Suhat/.ssh/id_rsa. this full path right?

Answer (score 1):

I felt in the same problem.
From my terminal I could connect to the remote host.
With password specified or content of the privateKey in filesystems.conf, that worked too, but impossible to make it work setting the privateKey as a path.
After some tries I finally solved it.
My laravel 5.8 filesystems.conf

```
'sftp' => [
    'driver' => 'sftp',
    'host' => 'HOST',
    'username' => 'LOGIN',
    'privateKey' => base_path() . '/ssh/myPrivateKey',
    'root' => env('MY_PATH'),
    'timeout' => 30,
],
```

the stupid thing I was doing was using

```
'privateKey' => 'ssh/myPrivateKey',
```

and believing Laravel will find it.
Replacing it with

```
'privateKey' => base_path() . '/ssh/myPrivateKey',
```

And all went fine :)

Next thing to do is to allow your apache user (www-data/nobody/whatever) to read this file. `chown` is good for that.

To check your key before enering panic mode just try to ssh without any agent.

```
ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o IdentityFile=/path/to/my/privateKey LOGIN@HOST
```

Thanks to https://superuser.com/a/268777/911570 for this last part.

Answer (score 0):

It won't accept  PPK or PEM as file.

You need to put the whole key in privateKey field

```
'sftp' => [
    'driver' => 'sftp',
    'host' => env('SFTP_HOST'),
    'port' => env('SFTP_PORT', 22),
    'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
    'privateKey' => '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIG4gIBAAKCAYEAxXDGR43F1xLoaJBC3hLC5RECX89Ost5rVTBsefj5vnoms8V2
RoUGWIZrzK3v8u+ALcfdcAIRFrFd4XM4KeDUBaRQ6a8hc8qFowF7SMATfVnVjInW
',
    'root' => env('SFTP_ROOT'),
],
```